# How to browse the value of a formGroup?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I browse the value of a formGroup using the module **ReactiveFormsModule**

```
createForm() {
  this.form = this._FormBuilder.group({ // <-- the parent FormGroup
    formation59: this.formation59,
    dateSaisie: this.dateSaisie
  });
}

for (let i=0; i<this.form.value.length; i++) {
  console.log(this.form.value[i]);
}
```

I use Angular 5.2, bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "browsing".

You can display the value :

```
console.log(this.form.value);
```

You can also iterate over each value :

```
this.form.controls.forEach((control: FormControl) => console.log(control.value));
```

Answer (score 2):

The form group has an object literal called `controls` which you can iterate through using `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => { 
  console.log(this.form.get(key).value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through `formControls` instead of `formGroup`.

```
this.form.controls.forEach((control) => {
     console.log(control.value);
});
```